Unable to add existing nic with application security group & nsg to vm using azure bicep
Unable to add existing nic with application security group & nsg to vm using azure bicep.
My code like this
resource existing 'Microsoft.Network/networkinterfaces@2022-04-02'existing = {
name : 'mechnic'
}
Please advice how to fix this issue.

Could you provide more information? In this case, are the NIC and NSG existing resources that need to be attached to the ASG and VM respectively? Is this what you're expecting? @SatyaB

Hi, only NIC is existing resource it should be  attach to nsg, asg & vm using azure bicep
